# Pair object overriding equals so that reverse pairs are also the same

Tags: java, equals

I want to define a Pair class in which <2,3> and <3,2> is the same thing. The equal method is overridden, but I'm not sure how to override the hashcode function to match that. The code I have so far is:

```
 Set<Pair> edgePairs=new HashSet<>();

    edgePairs.add(new Pair(2,3));
    edgePairs.add(new Pair(2,4));
    edgePairs.add(new Pair(2,5));
    edgePairs.add(new Pair(4,2));
    edgePairs.add(new Pair(2,3));
    edgePairs.add(new Pair(3,2)); 

    for (Pair edgePair : edgePairs) {
        System.out.println(edgePair.x+" "+edgePair.y);
    }
```

output:

```
2 3
2 4
2 5
4 2
3 2
```

The correct output should not contain pairs <4,2> and <3,2>

Pair Class:

```
 public class Pair
{
    int x, y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;  this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pair that = (Pair) o;
        if ((x == that.y && y == that.x)||(x == that.x && y == that.y))                
              return true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x; result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like not correct.Make sure that the hashcode always return same result if the equals is true between two object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just make your `hashCode` return `x + y`, without multiplying either of them by 31, then the order of parameters won't matter.

Comment: That will result in a lot of hash collisions. Consider 2 + 7, will result in the same hashcode as 3 + 6 and 4 + 5 and 1 + 8 and 0 + 9.

Comment: [HashSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.hashCode%28%29)'s implementation of `hashCode` is instructive here; they'd sum the _hashcodes_ of x and y.

Comment: @AndrewRueckert That makes no difference, since the `Integer` class's implementation of `hashCode` is just to return the value.

Comment: @kami yes. If you had 3 + 6, it would then reject 4 + 5, 2 + 7, 1 + 8, etc.

Comment: I've inserted <3,6> followed by <4,5> and <2,7>, they are all added to the Set like it should (not rejected) with the `x+y hashCode`. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: In terms of behavior, hash collisions are not a problem. It's performance that could suffer. If you're curious why, you should look up how hash tables work (it's a common DSA topic).

Comment: @TheCrzyMan no, they're not rejected. The map just works less efficiently if you have lots of collisions. My algorithm here spreads hash values equally given an equal distribution of the possible inputs. So without making assumptions about which `int` values are more likely to appear in the input than others, you can't improve on it.

Comment: @Dawood I was under the impression that was for hashmaps not hashsets as OP is using

Comment: It applies to both. @TheCrzyMan

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

The way I am interpreting the Java docs disagree. I read it as both will associate a single unique element to the hash.

Comment: Try it and see for yourself @TheCrzyMan

Comment: @Dawood I may tomorrow, but it would seem against the whole point of having a set if you could have duplicates.

Comment: They're not duplicates. Just pairs with the same hash code. It would be against the whole point of a set if you couldn't store two different elements with the same hash code.

Answer (score 0):

You are really close, you just need to make the hash function more specific

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    if (x > y) {
        a = x;
        b = y
    } else {
        a = y;
        b = x;
    }
    int result = a; result = 31 * result + b;
    return result;
}
```

Or you can redo your `Pair` class and make the storage of x and y in ascending order.

Either way, you need to separate the order of the variables in your hash equation from the order the variables were entered.